# Selecting value from select list using jquery using .class identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am I doing wrong or how should I approach this.

Look at the following fiddle:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicholas116/1g5jg5fv/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".metric_div").hide();

  $("#solid_radio").click(function() {
    $("#solid").show();
    $("#liquid").hide();
    $("#volume").hide();
    $("#none").hide();
  });

  $("#liquid_radio").click(function() {
    $("#solid").hide();
    $("#liquid").show();
    $("#volume").hide();
    $("#none").hide();
  });

  $("#volume_radio").click(function() {
    $("#solid").hide();
    $("#liquid").hide();
    $("#volume").show();
    $("#none").hide();
  });

  $("#input1").change(function() {
    console.log($("#input1").val());
    var input1 = $("#input1").val();

    console.log('multiplier: ' + get_multiplier());
    $("#result").val(input1 * get_multiplier());
  });

  function get_multiplier() {
    var multiplier = $(".multiplier option:selected").val();
    return multiplier;
  }

});
```

- User selects "solid(g)" radio button
- Jquery .show() invoked and dropdown appears
- "KG" is selected on dropdown. value = 1000
- getMultiplier() function *should* return 1000 but it does not
- Why

Comment: Returns 1000 for me, seems OK

Comment: Given the steps you describe, the code works fine for me. What issue are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you're declaring the `class` attribute twice on your `select` elements:

`<form class="form-control" class="multiplier">`

instead of

`<form class="form-control multiplier">`

The second issue is that you have multiple elements with the `multiplier` class, so when you select `$(".multiplier option:selected").val()` it's retrieving the value of the first element with the `multiplier` class. You need to get the value of the visible `multiplier` element:

`$(".multiplier:visible option:selected").val()`

#### [Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g5jg5fv/2/)

Comment: awesome. thanks. i hope one day i'll be as experienced as you.